# Android Gradient on Lollipop not working. - API 21

Tags: android, gradient, android-5.0-lollipop

When I try to use Gradient on Lollipop, it doesnt work.
While it works on all previous versions.

Here is my example:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient android:type="radial" android:gradientRadius="500"
    android:startColor="#00417e" android:endColor="#001b34" />
```

Comment: Radial gradients are broken in Lollipop, bug report https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77862

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is a bug. Check this here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77862

[image]

Comment: The workaround is described on the link.   I am just wondering if that workaround could break or even work when 5.0.x or 5.x gets out.

Comment: The workaround will continue to work in future versions. I've updated the linked AOSP issue tracker bug to reflect this.

Comment: @alanv Someone in ASOP is closing all important bugs in past some days without any kind of comments. Some bugs are really important...What are you guys doing? http://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/2on1fe/google_closed_11889_android_bugs_last_48_hours/

Comment: Thanks @Krupal Shah! Before reading this answer I spent 2 hours trying different solutions while this stupid and annoying issue was driving me crazy.

Answer (score 23):

I had the same problem and created 2 different files:

in drawables

```
android:gradientRadius="270"
```

and in drawables-v21

```
android:gradientRadius="270dp"
```

Now it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

```
int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (sdk < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        //in your gradient use android:gradientRadius="500"
    } else {
      // in your gradient use android:gradientRadius="80%p" or 
      // android:gradientRadius="200dp"
```

Try write two different xml files using different gradientRadius style

Answer (score 0):

Seems I found another workaround - set gradient background in code:

```
findViewById(R.id.bg).setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context,R.drawable.bg_gradient));
```

Comment: For me this ends with the same results that setting `android:background` in xml.

Answer (score -1):

use like this will be fine:

```
android:gradientRadius="50%p"
```

Comment: This is not a complete solution: it produces a gradient on my Lollipop 5.0.2 (api 21), but on my KitKat 4.4.2 (API 19) it's filled with `endColor`.