# Android radial gradient before API 21

Tags: android, android-drawable, radial-gradients

I'm trying to use the following drawable containing a radial gradient as the background of a view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:top="3dp" android:left="3dp" >
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <gradient android:gradientRadius="50dp"
                android:startColor="#0000ff"
                android:centerColor="#00ff00"
                android:endColor="#ff0000"
                android:type="radial" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

On API < 21 the gradient is not displayed, only the `endColor` without any gradient.

Is it a known issue that radial gradient is not supported on API < 21 and is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

You have a similar question: [Android Gradient on Lollipop not working. - API 21](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27384655/android-gradient-on-lollipop-not-working-api-21)

> It is a bug. Check this here:
>   https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77862

It gives you a workaround

Comment: That seems a bit different: for me it works on 21 and later, but not on previous versions