# Gradient not working for Lollipop API 21

Tags: android, imageview, android-5.0-lollipop, gradient, linear-gradients

Here is the gradient.xml that I am applying on my ImageView.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:angle="180"
        android:endColor="#BF000000"
        android:startColor="#00000000"/>
</shape>
```

I did look at this post - [Android Gradient on Lollipop not working. - API 21](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27384655/android-gradient-on-lollipop-not-working-api-21), but my problem is, im not using radial gradient. Hence Im not including gradientRadius in my xml file.

Any easy way to fix this?

If nothing works them I was thinking of creating a new bitmap, applying a gradient to it and then setting that to the ImageView [I know, its ugly].

Any help will greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem.

I inserted the "ImageView" into "FrameLayout" and applied the shape.

For example

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:foreground="@drawable/gradient">
     <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

I hope that this can help you :)