# Spinner background is not correct on Android 6.0+

Tags: android, android-spinner

I use Android project(old project) on Eclipse.

I install ADT from here:

```
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
```

In my manifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

snippet of xml layout:

```
  <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/currencySpinner"
        style="@style/racommon_spinner_custom_style"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:prompt="@string/currency" />
```

here styles.xml

```
  <style name="racommon_spinner_custom_style" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/racommon_spinner_custom_bg</item>
    <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
</style>
```

Here drawable **racommon_spinner_custom_bg**:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_selected_custom_border"/>

    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_pressed_custom"/>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_default_custom" />
</selector>
```

here `res\drawable-mdpi\spinner_pressed_custom.9.png`

[image]

Here result on Android 4.3
[image]

and here result on Android 6.0+
[image]

Here when click on spinner:
[image]

As you can see the background of spinner is different than on Android 4.0. On android 4.0. is correct spinner's background. But in android 6.0+ not correct.

Here result nine-pathch generator
[image]

Why?

Comment: Show the code for `@drawable/spinner_default_custom` & others

Comment: @AntonMalyshev "spinner_default_custom" is png file. This is a black triangle in the bottom right corner

Comment: Looks like the shadow gradient is not rendering correctly.. How does this one looks like? `spinner_selected_custom_border` | Also, Are the pics you posted from a physical device or from the eclipse preview software?

Comment: @HedeH if I migrate to Android Studio this problem will be fix?

Comment: Shouldn't be related to the IDE, please post the `spinner_selected_custom_border`

Comment: @HedeH /spinner_selected_custom_border.9.png - this is a red triangle in the bottom right corner when user click on spinner. I update my post.

Comment: its a problem of dpi, so i suggest you to design 9 Patch images According to device dpi.

Comment: if I remove "style" from spinner I get same incorrect result. So maybe problem is not in custom style

Answer (score 0):

[image]**I think its a problem of dpi, so i would suggest you make 9 patch image according to dpi**

go to Below Link

[Click Here](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html#&sourceDensity=320&name=example)

and Drag your current 9 patch image here, it will generate the images according to  dpi.

Comment: it's not help. Same result.

Comment: have you dragged the result image showing in preview module?

Comment: Yes, I download zip  and extract it to the 'res' folder.

Comment: i have updated Screenshot, is your view is similar tho preview section on screenshot?

Comment: I have updated my post. No I have not same preview and as your preview.

Comment: then move your cursor over image in preview and stretch it.

Comment: I scratch but it not correct. Red line is now of whole spinner. How correct scratch as on your example?

Comment: means you have stretched max, you need to sort out it by stretching few values.

Answer (score 0):

Since you aren't setting gradient background programmatically, the problem is just with the style used from deprecated theme: `Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner`.

Just replace it with up to date theme like `Widget.AppCompat.Light.Spinner`.

Also you can try just to update `targetSdkVersion` and use more recent SDK version if that's an option for you.

Some clarification:
the actual cause of the gradients to be broken on newer Android versions is the new requirement to specify values in dp, see [Android Gradient on Lollipop not working. - API 21](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27384655/android-gradient-on-lollipop-not-working-api-21)

Comment: I get error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.Spinner'

Comment: If I use this: parent="Widget.AppCompat.Spinner" then I get same error. Not correct background on spinner.

Comment: Then probably the only way to go is to update Android SDK version used